# Arguments for Primitive Recursive Arithmetic + \epsilon_0 Induction being "True"

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, meta-math, transfinite-induction

Gentzen presented a proof of the consistency of PA.  This proof can be formalized in PRA (Primitive Recursive Arithmetic) + "Transfinite Induction up to $\epsilon_0$".  In order to accept this proof as valid finitistically, you have to decide whether or not you accept the PRA + "$\epsilon_0$-induction" to be true.  In [this paper](https://www.danielwaxman.com/files/gentzen.pdf), Waxman gives an argument that this does not hold as a complete finitistic or epistemological argument for Con(PA). Are there other positions? I'm interested in reading some arguments that this is finitistic in a looser sense.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1vBesOFURek works for me.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thats a pretty strong argument!